# Who carried the kiyor?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, levites-leviyim, dor-hamidbar, parshat-nasso, bamidbar-parsha

In Parshas Bamidbar and Nasso the Pesukim list which families in Shevet Levy carried which items in the Mishkan. However nowhere does it say who carried the kiyor. Who carried it? Why doesn't it say who carried it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple opinions

1. Ramban שמות לח/כא and Sefer Chassidim offer an opinion that בני קהת carried it
2. אבן עזרא(שמות לה/טז) & חזקוני (שמות ל/יח) say that it might have been either בני גרשון or בני מררי
3. אזנים לתורה (שמות לה/טז) suggests that the כיור was probably submerged in the באר overnight (similar to what was done in the בית המקדש) so that the water within it wouldn't become  פסול overnight. The באר wasn't carried by anyone, it made the journey on its own and as such it carried the כיור with it.

See the discussion [here](https://tora-forum.co.il/viewtopic.php?t=5649) for further reference.

Comment: I looked up the references it doesn't say who carried it. We could deduce from. there who carried it. But It makes sense though.